# In R read.csv, how to avoid long numeric variable to be truncated?

Tags: r, import, precision, read.csv

There is a text file ('mt.txt'), when I use 'read.csv' ,the variable V30 tail is replaced by zero, because the length is very big (refer to below V30 table). How can I solve it? Thanks.

```
V30
92748999985195543475049289
92748999985195543475049265
92748999985195543400030542
92748999985195543475049227
```

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what your actual issue is. What R prints there is not what is stored internally. See, e.g., `print(DF$V30, digits = 22)`. However, there is a loss of precision because R imports these as floating-point numbers, see `sprintf("%f", 92748999985195543475049289)`. You would need a to use a package that provides big integers or arbitrary precision numbers if you want to avoid that. But that could limit what you can do with these numbers.

Comment: Assuming these are some IDs, if you are not going to do any arithmetic operations on these numbers, then read them as character. `read.table(... colClasses = "character")` By the way read.csv is just a wrapper for read.table. As your input is not CSV, maybe use read.table instead.

Comment: @zx8754  thanks for you replay , that's what i want , i update my code as " 
   read.csv('mt.txt',sep='\t',colClasses = "character")  " , the result is great. Thanks.

Comment: Great, closed this post with relevant posts which used the "colClasses" approach as a solution.